# oneof CustomType protobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto

I am tyring to replicate python schema code to golang(protobuf). I am stuck in 1 of the condition.

```
message Type1 {
 enum Type{
 type1 = 1
}
Type type = 0;
string name = 1;
}

message Type2 {
 enum Type{
 type2 = 1
}
Type type = 0;
string name = 1;
repeated string value = 2;
}

message Type3 {
 enum Type{
 time = 1
}
Type type = 0;
string name = 1;
string format = 2;
string value = 3;
}

message Request {
something 
something
map<string, oneof_above_defined_types> params = n
}
```

How do i make sure that map takes only custom types defined above?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to define a new type that includes the oneof type:

```proto
message TypeX {
   oneof type_oneof {
    Type1 type_1 = 1;
    Type2 type_2 = 2;
    Type3 type_3 = 3;
  };
}
message Request {
   ...
   map<string, TypeX> params = n;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i tried doing that but looks like schema changes and it is not compatible with previous one.

eg. 
{
"id":"some_id",
"random":"some_random",
"params":{
"random_name":{
"type":"type1",
"name":"name"
},
"random_2":{
"type":"type2",
"name":"type2_name",
"value":"type2_value",
}
}

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Using `Request` as defined in my answer, your JSON would be `{"params":{"key-1":{"type_1":{"type":0,"name":"name-1"}},"key-2":{"type_2":{"type":0,"name":"name-2","value":["foo","bar","baz"]}},"key-3":{"type_3":{"type":0,"name":"name-3","format":"format-3","value":"value-3"}}}}`

Comment: **NOTE** Protobuf requires that enumerations start at 0 too because, if unset, these take the default value and this will be zero; so you need to have an equivalent.